# Mixture of past and present tense

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

Today I answered [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292546/anagrams-how-to-express-it-right) on ELU and included as my suggestion of the correct answer the following line (taken from the OP's own example):

> To his amusement, Jason realized that 'Madam Curie' is an anagram of 'Radium Came'

This was queried by another user, specifically my use of the present tense **"is an anagram"** as they felt the tense should match the tense of the comparison, i.e. "...was an anagram..."

In my explanation I replied:

> Because 'Madame Curie' *is* an anagram of 'Radium Came' throughout the continuum of time. Jason only *realised it* in the past.

However I am not sure of my ground here and perhaps I am incorrect, so I have since scoured ELU to try and find a grammatical rule for handling this and I was unable to.

Am I using the correct tense (and for the right reasons)? Is there a rule for this?

Edit: Not a duplicate of [She is/was going to the cinema](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70749/she-is-was-going-to-the-cinema) because that refers to a finite event in the past that does not continue into the present. I refer to something that was true *then* and is still true *now*, leading to the confusion about tenses.

Comment: Related question: [He didn't know that New Jersey was actually in the East Coast.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/he-didnt-know-where-new-jersey-was), and another one: [Past tense or present tense to describe something that happened in the past but is still true?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150709/past-tense-or-present-tense-to-describe-something-that-happened-in-the-past-but/150743#150743)

Comment: And here's another: [“I didn't know you liked her” or “I didn't know you like her”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149120/i-didnt-know-you-liked-her-or-i-didnt-know-you-like-her/149167#149167)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks... No closer to knowing the actual answer though (on first quick reading). I'll have to study those answers.

Comment: Wow. Lots of complaining about the lack of any hard rules, and people just doing what feels better. At least I'm not alone!

Comment: @Marv: I wouldn't get too hung up about whether to use past or present. There's no specific rule telling you exactly when you *can't* shift the tense in such contexts, but in general we tend to repeat the past tense unless there's some special reason why the "fact **reported** in the past" has specific relevance to current time of speaking.

Comment: Cool thanks @FumbleFingers - I like the accepted answer in http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150709/past-tense-or-present-tense-to-describe-something-that-happened-in-the-past-but/150743#150743 It says both are acceptable and explains the difference. However it was not highly upvoted. Still I feel I need to stand marginally corrected in the original thread, Mr Lister triumphs :)

Comment: @Marv: Yes, I'm sure Mr Lister's "just feels better" accurately reflects average preference among native speakers for the context on that ELU question. Unless said in some context where the fact that those letters could be thus anagrammaticized was *currently* relevant, I think nearly everyone would simply maintain tense consistency with the main verb ***realized***.

Comment: Someone needs to add an answer so I can accept it! :)

Comment: @Marv: Nah. Someone needs to add their vote to the existing four that recognise this question as a duplicate.